# Scroll page with a fixed amount of pixels AND doing it from the scroll wheel

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of elements and I want to move from one to another using the scroll wheel, but the problem is that I cannot make the mouse scroll wheel to scroll the page with a fixed amount of pixels.
I am trying to do this in Angular2, but also a pure JavaScript solution would be helpful. My code looks like this:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const st = window.pageYOffset;
    if (st > this.lastScrollTop) {
        this.goToNext();
    } else {
        this.goToPrevious();
    }
    this.lastScrollTop = st;
  }

goToNext = () => {
    window.scrollBy(0, 210);
}

goToPrevious = () => {
    window.scrollBy(0, -210);
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that the `goToNext()` and `goToPrevious()` functions are called multiple times for each time I am scrolling the page. So I tried to prevent the default event of scroll and then scroll (with the fixed amount of pixels) the page using  `window.scrollBy(x, y)`.
I am able to navigate from one item to another with `goToNext()` and `goToPrevious()` and using the Up and Down arrows from the keyboard, buy I need to make it possible also using the mouse wheel. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: To be more specific: when I scroll down from the mouse wheel, I want the page to scroll with an exact amount of pixels (210 for now). So even if I scroll harder, or normal, or in any other way, I need the page to scroll with the same amount of pixels. Then, on another scroll, the page should scroll again with 210px. The idea is to have the items always on the same place on the page. At this moment, when I scroll, many scroll events are taking place, so my scroll functions `goToNext()` and `goToPrevious()` are called multiple times (once per each scroll event) and the page is basically scrolled to the bottom of it.

I am trying to replicate the behavior they have here:

> https://admin.typeform.com

when you create a new form from a template (Registration Form). They don't have exactly what I want to achieve, but I am trying this 'scroll' trick in order to avoid having 2 items inactive at the same time.

Comment: Could you explain how it doesn't work? What is exactly the expected behaviour. As it is described in your post, your code works in my test

Comment: can you try [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)?

Comment: Yes, that's on the 3rd line of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do,

I will attach a listener to `keydown` and `mousewheel` events, then to stop the default scrolling call `preventDefault` from there. Then call functions `scrollDown` or `scrollUp` depending on what direction the event points.

you can use `e.deltaY` for `onwheel` and `e.key` for `onkeydown`.

Below is a sample snippet. Of course, it's your task to add a smooth scrolling effect.

```js
window.onwheel = beforeScroll;
window.onkeydown = beforeScroll;
var scrollVal = 0;
function beforeScroll(e) {
    if (e.type == 'wheel') {
        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            scrollUp();
        } else {
            scrollDown();
        }
    }
    else if (e.type == 'keydown' && (e.key == 'ArrowDown' || e.key == 'ArrowUp')) {
        if (e.key == 'ArrowDown')
            scrollDown();
        else if (e.key == 'ArrowUp')
            scrollUp();
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return;
}

function scrollUp() {
    if (scrollVal > 0)
        scrollVal -= 200;

    this.scroll(0, scrollVal);
}

function scrollDown() {
    if (scrollVal < document.body.scrollHeight)
        scrollVal += 200;
    //should detect for maximum scroll
    this.scroll(0, scrollVal);
}
```

```css
.demo {
  width: 100%;
}

.demo .content:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  <div class="content"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>2</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>3</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>4</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>5</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>6</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>7</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>8</h1></div>
  <div class="content"><h1>9</h1></div>
</div>
```